# ckeditor filebrowserImageUploadUrl sending full path stripped of all "\" in ie and edge

Tags: upload, ckeditor, image-uploading

This question is being asked as part of the CKEditor forum apparently now hosted on stackoverflow.  I am treating this entry as a forum question.  I hope it will appear in the correct place on the stackoverflow site.  Please advise if it should be redirected.

I am using the filebrowserImageUploadUrl config setting in a ckeditor instance.

In Firefox or Chrome, when I click on the "Upload" tab to view images on the local device, select one, and click "Send it to Server," the value transferred to the server by ckeditor is simply the file name and extension.  The url saved and returned is correct, and all works fine.

In IE11 (and earlier?) and the new MS Edge, the filename sent to the server is the full path name stripped of all "\" separators.  So, for example, the file on a Windows PC named "C:\Users\username\Pictures\imagename.jpg" is sent as "C:UsersusernamePicturesimagename.jpg".

I verified this by simply returning the string "upload.FileName" in the ckeditor dialog callback, where "upload" is the first parameter in the transmitted transaction and is declared on the server in C# as a HttpPostedFileWrapper.  The returned value in Firefox and Chrome are the filename.ext, while in IE and Edge, it was the stripped full path name described above.

Any ideas on why this might be the case?  Is there a known process/protocol for detecting this difference and dealing with it?

I forgot to mention that I am using ckeditor 4.5.3 (latest as of this writing).  The problem also occurs in release of 4.5.1 (earlier development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file name parameter sent to the server by ckeditor's upload (using various browsers for an MVC 5 website in Visual Studio 2015) turns out to be (1) only the filename.ext in Firefox, but (2) the full and correct file name in IE, *including* the "\" path separators.

So this is not a ckeditor issue.  It is instead a choice in browser security settings and/or defaults.  I am not sure what the IE default is (full path in my IE is disabled when I launch it directly, but is enabled when IE is used as the browser launched in Visual Studio).  So, obviously, the file name has to be parsed out of the path on the server side if and when the full path is provided.

Here are the two operative lines of C# MVC code that solved the problem (surrounded by some write's).  The controller does not assume what's coming.  If only the filename.ext is transmitted, that's what ends up as the ImageName.  If the full path, it parses it down to the filename.ext.

```
    public ActionResult ControllerName(HttpPostedFileWrapper upload, string CKEditor, string CKEditorFuncNum, string langCode)
    {
        . . .
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(upload.FileName);

        string ImageName = upload.FileName;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ImageName);

        ImageName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ImageName);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ImageName);
        . . .
    }
```

Using the writeline code, I was able to confirm the received value (either filename only or full path) and that the parse worked when needed but did not change the value when only the filename.ext was transmitted.

I hope this learning will be useful to others.  Sorry for the false alert.